# What are the major differences between asp.net core and asp.net core mvc application?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I don't see any difference except the folder structure in both of the applications. Please provide any information if you have.

Comment: What do you mean by `asp.net core`?

Answer (score 0):

For `Asp.Net Core`, there are main three project type, Asp.Net Core MVC, Asp.Net Core Web API and Asp.Net Core Razor PAGE.

For Asp.Net Core MVC and Web API, there are no much difference. MVC is used to return view, and api is used to return normally json object.

For Razor Page, it is totally different from MVC or web api, it follows handler pattern instead of controller action.

You could refer [Introduction to Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)